# Setting mouse position?

Tags: c++, wpf, xaml, visual-studio-2012, mouse

Well I'm working on a small program and I'm trying to set the position of the window's mouse to it's center every time it moves. Thing is I have no idea how to make this work. I had the following code:

```
auto point = new Point(300.0, 200.0);
//auto ends up being Windows::Foundation::Point;
```

But I could still move the mouse freely all over the screen...

So then I searched the internet a bit and used:

```
Windows::UI::Input::PointerPoint point = Point(300.0, 200.0);//1
//and//
auto point = Windows::UI::Xaml::PointHelper::FromCoordinates(300.0, 200.0);//2
```

And example one wouldn't compile. Example 2 did compile but I could still move the mouse acrros the whole screen.

Don't know if it's important but I'm coding in C++, using DirectX for graphics and XAML for Text. (I'm also using the base class as C++/CX to work with XAML).

Comment: What if the end user doesn't have a mouse (like me), or worse, has more than one? Why would you want them to not be able to use them/it?

Comment: @RowlandShaw. It's not that I don't want the end user to use the mouse. It's basically: Move mouse->Update Variable With Coordinates->Reset Mouse Position. That way you'll never reach the edge of the screen on can keep moving the mouse in any one direction if you wanted to. Well that's what I'm trying to do to implement a camera for DirectX.

Comment: "But I could still move the mouse freely all over the screen..." -- Simply assigning a Point to some variable called point won't affect the mouse. Perhaps you should actually post some *relevant* code from your program.

Answer (score 1):

Try using [SetCursorPos()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648394%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), it should work on Windows.

Comment: I went and tried the function but it didn't work. I included the WinUser header and in the cursor moved event I added: `SetCursorPos(300, 200);` But then the errors: `error C3861: 'SetCursorPos': identifier not found` and `IntelliSense: identifier "SetCursorPos" is undefined` appeared.

Comment: So you want the mouse to be centered all the time, even if you leave your window's area, right?

Comment: Yup. That's basically it. Though if the mouse coordinates themselves reset to the center of the screen it'll be easier to calculate how much someone moved the mouse since the last time they moved it. The biggest problem is that this isn't a win32 app and therefore I can't play with handles and such so I'm still at a lost...

Comment: Have you included `<windows.h>`. Also, you could try `System::Windows::Forms::Cursor::Position = Point(x, y)` if you're using windows forms.